# Showing external command output only if not empty

Tags: neovim, command-line, external-command

Is it possible to silently run an external command, but show the output on the prompt only if there was any?

Comment: You can try `let output = system(...)` and then check if output is not empty and echo output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If by external command you do mean shell commands then you can try using `system` function `:h system()`:

No output (on Windows)

```
let s:output = system("title")
if s:output != ''
    echom s:output
endif
```

Output

```
let s:output = system("date")
if s:output != ''
    echom s:output
endif
```